# How to correctly declare static refs in Composition API using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, reference, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using the Composition API (with `<script setup lang='ts'>`) to create a ref, used in my template:

```
const searchRef = ref(null)
onMounted(() => { searchRef.value.focus() })
```

It does work and my code compiles without errors. The IDE (JetBrains Goland or Webstorm), however, complains with `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`.

The hardcore solution is to use

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

but I would like to understand if there is a better way.

I was hoping for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to be a solution:

```
const searchRef = ref(null)
onMounted(() => { searchRef.value?.focus() })
```

The code still compiles and the app still works, but I now have `TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.`

What is the correct way to address this problem?

Comment: `null`'s type is inferred as `never` unless you tell the compiler otherwise. So you can use `ref<string | null>(null)` or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For template refs, pass a generic type argument to the `ref` at initialization. The generic type should match the type of the template ref's targeted element.

Here are some examples of template refs on native HTML elements:

```js
const htmlElemRef = ref<HTMLElement>()         // => type: HTMLElement | undefined
const inputRef = ref<HTMLInputElement>()       // => type: HTMLInputElement | undefined
const textareaRef = ref<HTMLTextAreaElement>() // => type: HTMLTextAreaElement | undefined
```

The `null` initialization is optional, and I often omit it for slightly more succinct code. The resulting type is `<T | undefined>`, which is more correct than `null` because the `ref` would actually be `undefined` if the element did not exist in the template. Optional chaining is still needed for the `ref`'s value (given that it's possibly `undefined`).

*Example:*

```js
const searchRef = ref<HTMLInputElement>()
onMounted(() => { searchRef.value?.focus() })
```

As @Kurt pointed out, template refs on Vue components require different typing. The generic type for the `ref` would be an [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) of the component's type (from a `.vue` import) ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs)):

```js
InstanceType<typeof MyComponentDefinition>
```

*Example:*

```js
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

const helloRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof HelloWorld>>()
```

Note: To use this with Volar in TypeScript files instead of Vue SFCs, make sure to enable [Volar's Takeover Mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#takeover-mode).

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue3-template-refs)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve this is to add the proper typings manually:

```
const searchRef: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null);
onMounted(() => { searchRef.value?.focus() });
```

Note: HTMLElement could be different if the the ref is targeting a Vue Component (e.g. `Ref<HTMLElement | Vue | null>`).